# Some kind of continuity of integrations

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f_{k} \in \mathcal{L}(E) (k = 1, 2,\dots, n ).$ and $E$ is a measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$. If $$ 0< \mathcal{L}^{1}(E) < \infty, \int_{E}f_{k}(x)dx = 0, (k = 1, 2,\dots, n ).$$ then for any $\lambda \in (0,1)$, there exists a measurable subset $e$ of $E$ with $\mathcal{L}^{1}(e) = \lambda \mathcal{L}^{1}(E)$ such that $\int_{e}f_{k}(x)dx = 0  (k = 1, 2,\dots, n )$

I have no idea so any help or try is appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to do it for a single $f$? I would start by splitting up $E$ into $E_-\cup E_0\cup E_+$ which are the sets where $f$ is respectively negative, zero, positive. Then, try to prove an analogue of the intermediate-value theorem so that you can balance out exactly the positive and negative contributions.

Comment: Oh, yes! I can solve the case of a single f following your hint.  Basically, $\int _{E_{-} \cap (-\infty, a)}f+ \int_{E_{+} \cap (-\infty, g(a))} f =0$ for some function $g$ and any $a$, and conclusion follows by finding an $a$ such that $m(E_{-} \cap (-\infty, a)) + m(E_{+} \cap (-\infty, g(a))) = \lambda m(E)$ and add a subset of $E_{0}$ if necessary.

Comment: But I am stuck with the case that $n>1$